# Изменение порядка блоков bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css3, bootstrap

Необходимо задать следующую разметку, используя bootstrap, согласно макету. Важно, чтобы была адаптивность.

**Декстоп и планшеты:**
[image: Десктоп]

**Мобильные:**
[image: Мобильные]